# Testing both LITTLE_ENDIAN and BIG_ENDIAN scenarios

Tags: java, nio, endianness

If I have a scenario where I need to handle `LITTLE_ENDIAN` and `BIG_ENDIAN` cases differently, how can I test the `BIG_ENDIAN` case if my system uses `LITTLE_ENDIAN`?  When the system's ByteOrder.nativeOrder().equals(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN), how do you test the case where ByteOrder.nativeOrder().equals(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)? because byteBuffer .order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN) is just changing the order on the bytebuffer but not the system right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). It has method [`order(ByteOrder bo)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order-java.nio.ByteOrder-):

> Modifies this buffer's byte order.
>
> **Parameters:**
> `bo` - The new byte order, either [`BIG_ENDIAN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteOrder.html#BIG_ENDIAN) or [`LITTLE_ENDIAN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteOrder.html#LITTLE_ENDIAN)

Note that the javadoc of `ByteBuffer` says:

> The initial order of a byte buffer is always [`BIG_ENDIAN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteOrder.html#BIG_ENDIAN).

*Example*

```
int value = 123456789;
byte[] bigEndian = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.BYTES)
        .order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)
        .putInt(value)
        .array();
byte[] littleEndian = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.BYTES)
        .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
        .putInt(value)
        .array();
System.out.printf("value = 0x%08x = %d%n", value, value);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bigEndian));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(littleEndian));
```

*Output*

```
value = 0x075bcd15 = 123456789
[7, 91, -51, 21]
[21, -51, 91, 7]
```

Comment: What about when the system's ByteOrder.nativeOrder().equals(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN) .  How do you test the case where ByteOrder.nativeOrder().equals(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)?  because byteBuffer .order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN) is just changing the order on the bytebuffer but not the system right?

Comment: @Artanis Nothing can change the byte order of the system. It's hardwired into the CPU. --- *"how do you test the case where ByteOrder.nativeOrder().equals(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)?"* Run the code on a system where the CPU is big-endian.

Comment: okay so my question is still how can you test the other scenario?

Comment: So i need to find a new computer with big endian to run my code on just to test its functionality, theres not another way?

Comment: @Artanis The entire point of Java is that it runs anywhere, which means that Java itself behaves the same on big-endian and little-endian systems. *Your* Java code should care what the native byte order is, unless it communicates with code written in a different language which does care.

Comment: @Artanis What are you trying to test? As I said, your Java code generally doesn't care what the systems byte order is. If you need to create files in big- vs little-endian order, you can test that regardless of what the systems byte order is.

Comment: I'm converting c# code to java.  The c# code checks if its little or big endian so it knows if it should reverse the array or not.   Are you saying I don't need to do that for java?

Comment: @Artanis Depends on what "array" you are referring to. If the array is e.g. a byte array from a file that is using the native byte order, then of course your code should use the native byte order, which it can do by using a `ByteBuffer` and calling `buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());`

Comment: the c# code has a byte array, checks if little or big endian, if little then it reverses array before converting to double.  My java code has a byte array coming from a result set that I also want to convert to double.   So do I need to check for little or big endian like the c# code does?

Comment: @Artanis It all depends: Is the data in the byte array in the database in big- or little-endian? It really doesn't matter what the system running your Java code is, it only matters what the data you're processing is. Remember, the data in the database might be accessed by multiple systems, which can be a mix of big- and little-endian systems. If all those systems must understand the data correctly, the **data** must be in a *well-defined* byte order. Once the data's byte order is well-defined, your Java code should use that byte order, and should care what the native byte order is.

Comment: "Once the data's byte order is well-defined, your Java code should use that byte order, and should care what the native byte order is" - do you mean "shouldn't care" here?  So if I'm dealing with a Java ByteBuffer (which is always big-endian) then I don't care what the system's native order is?

Comment: @Artanis Yes, sorry, the "n't" fell off there. `ByteBuffer` isn't always big-endian, it just *defaults* to big-endian. You should figure out what the byte order of the ***data*** is, and tell `ByteBuffer` so it can handle the data correctly for you.